# Natural numbers proof via Peano's axioms (not trichotomy)

Tags: peano-axioms

Prove that for each $x,y$ an element of the natural numbers ($\mathbb{N}$), $x<y$ or $x=y$ or $x>y$. So at least one is true. I have the definition of order to work with and the basic algebra of the natural numbers to work with (i.e. commutativity of add./mult., associativity of add./mult., etc.). I figured it best to begin by doing this by cases. So, for case 1: assume $x\nless y$ and $x\neq y$, show $x>y$. I'm not sure, however, what $x\nless y$ and $x\neq y$ allows me to conclude. Thanx for the help and my apologies for the formatting.

Comment: What is the definition of order that you have?

Comment: For x, y ∈ N, we say that x < y if and only if ∃k ∈ N such that y = x+k.
For x, y ∈ N, x ≤ y if and only if x < y or x = y. For x, y ∈ N, x > y if and only if y < x. For
x, y ∈ N , x ≥ y if and only if y ≤ x

Comment: The key here is that every natural number can be constructed as a successor of $1$.  If this weren't true then trichotomy would not hold.

Comment: Ah, yes, however, I am not proving trichotomy I just want to show that at least one of x<y or x=y or x>y is true, not that at most one is. Sorry if I'm misinterpreting what you are trying to convey.

Comment: There is no difference, as it is very simple to prove that at most one of these is true.  The hard part is the part you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction on $x$.

Base case: $x=1$.  Then either $y=1$ (and $x=y$) or $y\neq 1$, and then $x<y$ because each natural number is a successor of $1=x$.

Inductive case: $x\neq 1$.  This breaks into two parts:
1. $y=1$.  Then $x>y$, since each natural number except $1$ is a successor of $1=y$.
2. $y\neq 1$.  Then both $x,y$ are successors, so we apply the inductive hypothesis to $x-1, y-1$.  Either $x-1<y-1$, $x-1=y-1$, or $x-1>y-1$.  In the first case, $x-1+k=y-1$, so $x+k=y$ and hence $x<y$.  The last two cases are similar.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I was leaning towards induction but was not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Glad to help, you're welcome.

Comment: Ok, so I concluded both other cases, however, I am unsure of the x-1=y-1 case. How can I conclude that x-1=y-1 implies x=y via the given definition of order? Would it be via the cancellation property of addition? That wouldn't work because 1 isn't an element of N. So could I apply the induction hypothesis to x+1 and y+1? Making the cancellation for addition a valid justification?

Comment: If two numbers are equal, then their successors are equal -- this should be one of the properties of equality you have.

Comment: Correct, however, are you saying that I am allowed to state the successor of x and y as x-1 and y-1 respectively? What I have is a conditional statement for all x,y an element of N, x'=y' implies x=y. Are you saying the converse is true as well?

Comment: When I write "$x-1$" this is shorthand for "$x'$, whose successor is $x$".  There is no subtraction defined.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I haven't seen it represented that way before. So you are saying that x-1 is defined as x successor whose successor is x?